# Azure policy "DeployIfNotExists" to multiple resources with one policy definition

Tags: azure, azure-policy

Is it possible to append multiple resources within one azure policy definition? My goal is to create one policy that would add diagnostic settings to all azure virtual desktop resources: application groups, hostpools and workspaces.

One policy for one resource type is working fine, but I cannot get it to work with all of them combined.

The "type" property within "resources" array cannot have any functions. That is the bottleneck for me. Maybe I`m missing something? Thanks in advance.

This is one of my approaches:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "displayName": "Enable Diagnostic Settings for AVD Resources to Log Analytics workspace",
        "policyType": "Custom",
        "mode": "Indexed",
        "description": "Deploys the diagnostic settings for AVD resources to stream to a Log Analytics workspace when any AVD resource missing this diagnostic setting is created or updated. The policy will set the diagnostic with all categories enabled.",
        "metadata": {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "category": "Monitoring"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "effect": {
                "type": "String",
                "metadata": {
                    "displayName": "Effect",
                    "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy."
                },
                "allowedValues": [
                    "DeployIfNotExists",
                    "Disabled"
                ],
                "defaultValue": "DeployIfNotExists"
            },
            "logsEnabled": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "True",
                "allowedValues": [
                    "True",
                    "False"
                ],
                "metadata": {
                    "displayName": "Enable logs",
                    "description": "Whether to enable log stream to the Log Analytics workspace - True or False"
                }
            },
            "settingsName": {
                "type": "String",
                "metadata": {
                    "displayName": "Setting name",
                    "description": "Name of the diagnostic settings."
                },
                "defaultValue": "AVD_Monitoring"
            },
            "logAnalytics": {
                "type": "String",
                "metadata": {
                    "displayName": "Log Analytics workspace",
                    "description": "Specify the Log Analytics workspace the AVD resources should be connected to.",
                    "strongType": "omsWorkspace",
                    "assignPermissions": true
                }
            },
            "profileName": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "AVD_Monitoring",
                "metadata": {
                    "displayName": "Profile name",
                    "description": "The diagnostic settings profile name."
                }
            }
        },
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "anyOf": [
                    {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/applicationGroups"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/hostPools"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/workspaces"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
                "details": {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings",
                    "existenceCondition": {
                        "allOf": [
                            {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs.enabled",
                                "equals": "true"
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "microsoft.insights/diagnosticSettings/logs[*].categoryGroup",
                                "equals": "allLogs"
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/workspaceId",
                                "equals": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "deployment": {
                        "properties": {
                            "mode": "incremental",
                            "template": {
                                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "settingsName": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "logAnalytics": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "resourceName": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "profileName": {
                                        "type": "String"
                                    },
                                    "logsEnabled": {
                                        "type": "String"
                                    },
                                    "location": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "variables": {},
                                "resources": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/workspaces/providers/diagnosticSettings",
                                        "apiVersion": "2021-05-01-preview",
                                        "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceName'), '/Microsoft.Insights/', parameters('profileName'))]",
                                        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "properties": {
                                            "workspaceId": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]",
                                            "logs": [
                                                {
                                                    "categoryGroup": "allLogs",
                                                    "enabled": "[parameters('logsEnabled')]"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/hostpools/providers/diagnosticSettings",
                                        "apiVersion": "2021-05-01-preview",
                                        "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceName'), '/Microsoft.Insights/', parameters('profileName'))]",
                                        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "properties": {
                                            "workspaceId": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]",
                                            "logs": [
                                                {
                                                    "categoryGroup": "allLogs",
                                                    "enabled": "[parameters('logsEnabled')]"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/applicationGroups/providers/diagnosticSettings",
                                        "apiVersion": "2021-05-01-preview",
                                        "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceName'), '/Microsoft.Insights/', parameters('profileName'))]",
                                        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "properties": {
                                            "workspaceId": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]",
                                            "logs": [
                                                {
                                                    "categoryGroup": "allLogs",
                                                    "enabled": "[parameters('logsEnabled')]"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "outputs": {}
                            },
                            "parameters": {
                                "settingsName": {
                                    "value": "[parameters('settingsName')]"
                                },
                                "logAnalytics": {
                                    "value": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]"
                                },
                                "profileName": {
                                    "value": "[parameters('profileName')]"
                                },
                                "resourceName": {
                                    "value": "[field('name')]"
                                },
                                "logsEnabled": {
                                    "value": "[parameters('logsEnabled')]"
                                },
                                "location": {
                                    "value": "[field('location')]"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This approach landed some results, it would update the resources but overall shows failed, because it tries to find all three types within one resource. Looking for a way to bypass this.

```
"resources": [
                    {
                      "if": {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/applicationGroups"
                      },
                      "then": {
                        "type": "Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/applicationGroups/providers/diagnosticSettings",
                        "apiVersion": "2021-05-01-preview",
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceName'), '/Microsoft.Insights/', parameters('profileName'))]",
                        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "properties": {
                          "workspaceId": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]",
                          "logs": [
                            {
                              "categoryGroup": "allLogs",
                              "enabled": "[parameters('logsEnabled')]"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "if": {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/hostPools"
                      },
                      "then": {
                        "type": "Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/hostPools/providers/diagnosticSettings",
                        "apiVersion": "2021-05-01-preview",
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceName'), '/Microsoft.Insights/', parameters('profileName'))]",
                        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "properties": {
                          "workspaceId": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]",
                          "logs": [
                            {
                              "categoryGroup": "allLogs",
                              "enabled": "[parameters('logsEnabled')]"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "if": {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/workspaces"
                      },
                      "then": {
                        "type": "Microsoft.DesktopVirtualization/workspaces/providers/diagnosticSettings",
                        "apiVersion": "2021-05-01-preview",
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceName'), '/Microsoft.Insights/', parameters('profileName'))]",
                        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "properties": {
                          "workspaceId": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]",
                          "logs": [
                            {
                              "categoryGroup": "allLogs",
                              "enabled": "[parameters('logsEnabled')]"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAESu.png)

Comment: Short answer is, yes, it is possible to have multiple deployment templates in one policy definition. But why on earth would you do that? You will undermine the purpose of Azure Policies. Having 1 policy initiative with multiple policies for various diagnostic settings is a much better way and best practice.